# how to access instance's 'this' in collection of objects

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects

I have created a object with constructor function. Then I stored it's 'this' value to a variable.

after creating few objects using 'new' I pushed them to an array. When I access the objects again, all the objects' 'this' value has become the last object created.

```
var t = function(x){
    j = this;
    this.u = x;
    this.k = function (){
        return j.u;
    }
}

var g = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    g.push(new t(i));
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    console.log(g[i].k());
```

**this prints ten '9's instead of 0 to 9.**

How can I access current instance's 'this' inside function. and access current object's details.

Answer (score 2):

Cause `j` is a global variable. Do:

```
  let j = this;
```

So then its part of thr closure.

Comment: Ugh, missing `var`/`let`/`const` strikes again. I call it [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use `var` to localize j's scope

```
var j = this;
```

**Demo**

```js
var t = function(x) {
  var j = this;
  this.u = x;
  this.k = function() {
    return j.u;
  }
}

var g = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  g.push(new t(i));
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(g[i].k());
```

Otherwise, since `j`'s scope is not localized to `t`, it's last value `9` is returned when you invoke `k()`.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers mentioned, you need to use `var` or `let` keywords, otherwise the `j` variable will be bounded to global scope.

```
var j = this;
```

One more thing to add, to prevent this kind of mistakes, you can specify:

```
'use strict'
```

at the top of your file which will inform you about this mistake by throwing an error your way. Using strict mode prevents you from accidentally binding variables to global scope.